# Tomcat 8 cannot deploy via Ant script

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, tomcat8

Tomcat Version: 8.0.43

OS: Windows 10

My Deploy URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/text

My user accounts appear to be setup properly as I can access the web UI just fine.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="user" password="pass" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I try to manually access that deploy URL in a browser I have no problems and I see this in my logs

`user [08/Oct/2018:12:51:15 -0700] "GET /manager/text/deploy?path=/apc HTTP/1.1" 200 69`

When I try to deploy via Ant I get the following error and log entry with a 401 unauthorized HTTP code

```
<target name="deploy" description="Install web application" depends="dist">
    <deploy url="http://localhost:8080/manager/text" username="user" password="pass"
        path="/apc" war="dist/apc.war"/>
</target>


java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java:3536)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java:3519)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:194)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: insufficient data written
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3558)
                at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
                at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:241)
                ... 17 more
```

`- [08/Oct/2018:12:52:14 -0700] "PUT /manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fapc HTTP/1.1" 401 2473`

The strange part is that my Undeploy Ant command works just fine using the same username and password.  So If I manually deploy my WAR I can successfully undeploy using this command

```
<target name="undeploy" description="Remove web application">
        <undeploy url="http://localhost:8080/manager/text" username="user" password="pass"
            path="/apc"/>
    </target>
```

`user [08/Oct/2018:12:47:34 -0700] "GET /manager/text/undeploy?path=%2Fapc HTTP/1.1" 200 61`

So it seems that my username and password are correct, but for whatever reason the deploy doesn't recognize it as valid

One thing to note is that the log entries for my successful manual access and undeploy attempts show the `user` in front of the entry.  The unsuccessful log entry for the deploy shows a `-` instead.  Not sure what that means but might be important.

**UPDATE:**
It appears it might have something to do with the tomcat 8 lib files.  Currently I use catalina-ant, tomcat-coyote, tomcat-util JAR's in my classpath to run my ant script.  If i use the lib's provided in Tomcat 8 I have those errors above.  If I instead use the libs from an old Tomcat 7 installation I have then it works fine.

Comment: If what you say is right then I'm guessing that when you do `"deploy"` it's using the user `-` and when you are using undeploy it's using the right user i.e. `user` you could confirm this using the following command in you ant `<echo>User is: ${username}</echo>`

Comment: Also the only difference is see among the 2 commands is `depends="dist"` so you may have to check the dependence also

Comment: @rohitthomas username and password are echo'ed correctly in deploy script.  I removed the "dist" dependency to verify and still has the same issue.

Comment: @rohitthomas please see update in OP.  Going to try upgrading Tomcat to latest 8.0.x version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authentication support is known to be broken in all version of Tomcat 8.0 later than 2017-05-30 (8.0.45 and later) -- see [issue #62809](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62809).

The issue #62809 has been fixed in Tomcat 9.0.13, 8.5.35, 7.0.92. It has not been fixed in Tomcat 8.0, as Tomcat 8.0 has already reached End of Life.

For reference: [r1796838](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1796838), [r1843992](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1843992).

> at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
>   at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:238)

The line numbers above are not from Tomcat 8.0.43 as you are claiming, but from 8.0.45 or later.
In 8.0.43 the "ostream.write(..)" call is on line 242 of `AbstractCatalinaTask`. In 8.0.45+ it is on line 238.

Comment: Your absolutely correct, I am using 8.0.47.  I had 8.0.43 installed and I guess still had that number on my mind when I posted.  Thank you.